# Regulating battery overvoltage to an IC pin

Tags: power

I am trying to find the best approach for ensuring a stable voltage on a specific pin of my gate driver IC chip during any potential battery overvoltage. I am currently using the Allegro A4960 for sensorless BLDC motor control, and am trying to crank the voltage up to 48 volts; however, the max rating for the Vbb pin is 50V while the Vbrg pin is 55V. After speaking to some of the engineers at Allegro, they mentioned that it is fine if the two voltages of Vbb and Vbrg are not the same so if I am not exceeding it for Vbrg then I should be fine to lower the voltage on Vbb. The Vbb current while operating is in the low mA range (approx 15-25mA).

My question is whether or not a simple zener and resistor network would be suitable for this sort of application. If so, where would the ideal location be to decouple any high frequency noise as the Vin of this network is part of a shared power plane with the inverter for the motor. More specifically, I must decouple as close to the chip as possible, should this be done before the zener and resistor network, within it, or both?

Thanks in advance, any assistance is deeply appreciated!

Comment: That part is officially Not Recommended for New Designs. Do you have the option of using another controller? Seems like it is not a great choice, considering that you want to operate within 2V of the absolute maximum, and Allegro is trying to discontinue it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always place decoupling caps as close to the chip as possible, after and voltage limiting device.

A Zener diode would be my solution to protect from overvoltage, but you have to be careful because they do not immediately start conducting at a specific voltage, so there is some range of voltage where the current increases.  So you don't want the Zener voltage too high, but at the same time if it's too low it may be partially conducting under normal voltage operations.  I'm not sure what you mean by using a resistor network with the Zener.  I voltage divider would be good for scaling down a voltage for an ADC or something similar (high-impedance), but if you are feeding power to something a resistor divider is not a good choice.  Maybe you meant a series resistor between source and pin, with a Zener on the pin.  That is OK if the resistor is not too big that it causes excessive voltage drop.

I would place the Zener close to the power source.  As you say there is a common power plane, so put it close to where that source is feeding into the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Although a zener would work to protect you from spurious voltage spikes, I would not use one on it's own to protect from an overage from a battery.

The battery will just fry your zener then your device. If over-voltage is a real and present danger, you really need to regulate the power to the device.

There are a myriad of circuits out there that you can use. Which one you choose will depend on a number of factors more related to your application.

Google "overvoltage protection circuit"